# Can't import appengine python module

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On my local machine I am unable to import appengine.ext module.

I have set the path using the following code

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine')
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')
```

Here is the error

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine')
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')
>>> from google import appengine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name appengine
>>> from google.appengine.ext import ndb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
>>>
```

Comment: no. its empty  >>> print sys.path[0] >>>

Comment: I have a google folder in the virtual env /env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google

Comment: Just tried it, and it did not work, I am getting the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110491/discussion-between-vinay-joseph-and-snakecharmerb).

Answer (score 1):

you should try to add the following code to the begining:

```
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

should work :).